# Is it possible for grub2 to detect some specific CPU features and choose a proper kernel to boot?

Tags: linux, kernel, configuration, grub2

I want to configure grub to check some CPU features on startup and choose a proper kernel to boot (e.g. multiple cores -> kernel with SMP support). Is it possible? If so, then how do I do it?

Answer (score 3):

I think syslinux can do this but I can't find the documentation - I remember using pxelinux to pick between 32/64-bit kernels.

For SMP, why not just make sure you're using a recent enough kernel with SMP alternatives enabled? That way the kernel itself will enable/disable SMP support if required.